# R: How to phrase iterating through a vector of unknown length

Tags: r, loops, vector, string-length

Figured it out.  Can delete.

I am looking for a single integer of the mean that minimized least squares for E yi(xi-u)^2 where "E" is grand summation. So, (1*((0.1-0.108)^2)) + (2*((0.11-0.108)^2)) + ...

How do you say this in R?  len isn't a function, and length uses the numeric value corresponding to the actual length...not iterate from beginning thorough however long.

```
 x<-c(0.1, 0.11, 0.111, 0.1111)
 y<-c(1, 2, 3, 4)
 avg = mean(x)
 for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    for (j in 1:length(y)) {
        mu = sum(j*(i-avg)^2) 
        print(mu)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. What's wrong with `i in 1:length(x)`? What output would expect from the code you are running?

Comment: Also see `?seq_len` and `?seq_along`

Comment: Seems like your python is rusty too...

Comment: It seems to me you want to use `for (i in x)` and `for (j in y)` which will work just fine in R. If you're trying to compute a weighted squared error of x then you should vectorize the calculation. What does `for i in len(vector)` do in python? Since `len(vector)` is not a list, I expect it just throws an error.

Comment: @JamesKing it indeed gives an error, exactly this: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: Yes, I meant len[vector].  Anyhow, I am looking for a single integer of the mean that minimized least squares for E yi(xi-u)^2 where "E" is grand summation.  So, (1*((0.1-0.108)^2)) + (2*((0.11-0.108)^2)) + ..

Comment: `len[vector]` makes even less sense. And that's an error message, too, of course. You cannot index a function, at least not `len`: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Sorry...long day and I'm a bit frazzled.  The question is rephrased to better articulate what my objective is.  And, as for vectorizing the calculation rather than using a 'for' loop...I am not sure what this mean.  The most similar examples I have from notes from the course I took used loops.

Comment: @JamesKing I am not sure what you mean by vectorizing the calculation.  Can you please show?

Answer (score 3):

I am entirely not sure what your question was, but will take the opportunity to say that

```
for (i in 1:length(x))
...
```

is not good practice, because it will break when `x` is of length 0. The reason is that `1:0` is `c(1,0)` in R:

```
1:0
# [1] 1 0
```

So, as @thelatemail already referred to them, `seq_len` or `seq_along` are the correct way to iterate over the indices on a vector or list:

```
for (i in seq_along(x))
...
```

It is a bit longer and less readable with `seq_len`:

```
for (i in seq_len(length(x)))
...
```

From your question it seems that you most likely want to iterate over the elements of the vector or list, so you can simply say

```
for (elem in x)
...
```

Also note that in R you can work with vectors instead of writing `for` loops.

Comment: I think `for (elem in x)` is what OP is thinking of, but this code will still not give the answer he wants. I think he just wants to do the calculation `sum(y*(x - mean(x))^2) = 0.0001365762`

Comment: @JamesKing: indeed, I didn't really look at the big picture. :)

Comment: Using seq_len I get the error "Warning message:
In seq_len(x) : first element used of 'length.out' argument"

Comment: @user3814464 Well if you keep doing things differently than you are told, then what can we do? :) Seriously, use one of the forms in my answer please. IF you insist on `seq_len`, I'll edit the question to add that. But you just want `for (i in x)`, or, even better, the vectorized form that @JamesKing gave you.